# JavaFX: Change font and size in a TextField

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

The default font settings in TextField depends on your Windows settings and when they are not the same I encounter display issues. So I want to set the TextField to a specific font and size but I don't know how to do it.
Could you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this way:

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
tf.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 70));
```

or for setting a custom font

```
tf.setFont(Font.loadFont("file:resources/fonts/isadoracyr.ttf", 120));
```

Ref: [Using Text and Text Effects in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/text/jfxpub-text.htm)

Comment: Thanks I was trying this on my container instead of my TextField that is the reason why it didn't worked.